# Dell Inspiron 15R (5520) Optical drive ejects randomly

Tags: inspiron, optical

**machine:** Inspiron 15R (5520)

**O.S:** dual boot Win10/ubuntu 18.04

I kept it on bios for 1 hour and it didn't ejected.

Doesn't happen when booted on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a software issue, but open terminal, and try `eject -i on`.

This will stop you from being able to open the disk tray via the button.

To renable opening via button, do `eject -i off`.

Test it to see if this works.

Comment: this will disable the h/w eject button, i don't think this is proper way to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Following command worked for me

```
eject -v -a off
```

Explanation:

-v   This  makes  eject  run  in verbose mode

-a on|1|off|0

This option  controls  the  auto-eject  mode,  supported  by  some
devices.When  enabled,  the drive automatically ejects when the device is closed.

to see all available option use

concise help

```
eject -h
```

full help

```
man eject
```